# Facing git not found in path when running flutter

Tags: flutter, git, dart, environment-variables, flutter-doctor

Every time I try to create a new flutter project, I face this errror:

> Project Creation Error Flutter create command was unsuccessful

Now when I run flutter doctor to diagnose the problem, the output I get is always the same:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwXmH.png)

> C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose Error: Unable to find git
> in your PATH.  Process finished with exit code 1

I have added flutter/bin git.exe and git/cmd in the Path in System variables:

> C:\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program
> Files\Git\cmd

I have installed the dart sdk as well through the command line.
I have reinstalled git and restarted my laptop to try and fix it but it didnt work.

What can I do to fix it?